# Do gitlab runners need to be re-registered after a migration if the external url does not change?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ee, gitlab-runner

I am migrating primary and secondary GitLab nodes to new nodes. In order to do this, I am following the backup and restore documentation.

Do GitLab runners need to be re-registered after a migration if the external url does not change?

Thanks all!!

Comment: It should not, no, because the runners use the URL, not an IP, when connecting to GitLab. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: I had the same challenge, installing new gitlab on new server, migration of groups and projects did well. but how can I register all the previous runners to new gitlab instance?

Answer (score 1):

No, GitLab runners do not need to be re-registered following a migration / backup/restore.

The runner registration is stored in GitLab's database and is associated with the token the runner receives from the `gitlab-runner register` command. Those tokens will continue to be valid, so long as they were properly backed up, probably even if the GitLab URL changes.

You can use the Runners API to [verify a runner token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#verify-authentication-for-a-registered-runner).